# How to center tikz picture in beamer slide and draw over it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to include a PNG picture to a slide and draw over it with tikz in overlays. I need to maintain the image still in the center of the page while I include the tikz drawings.

However, I cannot place the image in the center of the slide. Moreover, when I include tikz figures over the image, the image moves.

It is not clear either how to set the coordinates of the shapes over the figure.

How can I place the figure in the center of the slide and include tikz shapes over it at certain coordinates? Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c,plain]
\frametitle{New}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red,fill=black!2] (1,1) rectangle (2,5);
\draw[thick, -latex] (3,3) to (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}%

\end{document}
```

[image: fig]

Comment: Use the same tikzpicture!

Comment: I tried. But when the rectangle is over the image, the image moves down, as the rectangle overtakes the image. I need the image to stay still in the center.

Comment: try `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image in the centre of the page, you can position it at `current page.center`:

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c,plain]
\frametitle{New}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}};
\draw[red,fill=black!2] (1,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\draw[thick, -latex] (3,1) to (4,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, and I will add the other tikz shapes with `\only`.

Comment: @Andre Tikz commands are overlay aware, you can directly use something like `\draw<2->`. No need for `\only`